# Определить окончание подписки в Laravel используя mmanos/laravel-billing

Tags: php, laravel, биллинг

Использую плагин [mmanos/laravel-billing](https://github.com/mmanos/laravel-billing).

Я создаю подписку при помощи `$user->subscription( 'myplan')->create();`
План ориентирован на месяц.

```
INSERT INTO "main"."plans" (
    "id",
    "key",
    "name",
    "amount",
    "interval",
    "trial_period_days",
    "created_at",
    "updated_at",
    "deleted_at",
    "ROWID"
)
VALUES
    (
        1,
        'myplan',
        'My Plan',
        1000,
        'monthly',
        0,
        '2015-12-18 21:30:41',
        '2015-12-18 21:30:41',
        NULL,
        1
    );
```

На компьютере с Windows перевожу дату на пару месяцев вперед.
Проверяю, а подписка еще не закончена и метод `auth()->user()->subscribed()` возвращает значение `TRUE`.

Драйвер для билинга используется: Local (Non-production).
Как проверить, что подписка закончилась?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью метода `subscribed()` вы проверяете, подписана ли модель на приложение.

Скорее всего, вам нужно использовать метод `billingIsActive()`.
Он позволяет определить, имеет ли модель активную подписку в системе биллинга.
Метод не вернет `true`, если модель еще на пробном периоде (`trial`) и `cardUpFront` установлено равным `false` или подписка была отменена и находится на льготном периоде (`grace period`).